# Android ImageView doesn't fit with larger screens

Tags: android, android-imageview, tablet

I'm new to the Android development. I tested my android programme from the (eclipse)android emulator but when I run the same program in the SAMSUNG phone that has large screen and from the tablet my ImageView doesnt fit with their screen.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CompareActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/topbar" />

           <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#160203" >
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TabHost>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/crdt" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/registerbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/green" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/savings" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/blubutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerbutton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/blue" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/pl" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/redbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blubutton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/red" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/homlons" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/fd" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/orbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redbutton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/orange" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/pubutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/orbutton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/purple" />

            </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Phone view]

Comment: set android:scaleType="fitXY" to your ImageView.

Comment: which imageview doesnt fit screen ?

Comment: @Amrola both ImageViews

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot ?

Comment: doesnt fit width or hight ? or both ?

Comment: @Amrola doesnt fit width

Comment: imageView2 where it should be displayed ? 
could you provide a screenshot ? or at least a sketch about what layout are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The Layout is set to `wrap content` which will leave empty space in the larger screen. Notify the layout such that it takes all the space.

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/crdt" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/greenbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/green" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/savings" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:background="@drawable/savings"

Answer (score 0):

You can change your imageView XML as the below:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/crdt" />
```

or change it by code:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```